# What is the content under standalone\tmp\vfs in jboss 7 final

Tags: jboss7.x

I am using JBoss 7.0.0.Final. I find there is a lot of folders under  standalone\tmp\vfs directory and it occupies a lot of space . It seems they are unzipped content from the jars used by my project. Is there any method to disable such content because it occupies a lot of space in my dist?.why its created jar files in vfs?is there any helpfully to deployed application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible try a newer version of the application server. It looks like maybe you're hitting this bug https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-341.

Answer (score 2):

As James put it, its a BUG [AS7-341](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-341)

To get the best out of Jboss AS7, I advice use of nightly builds, you can get them here

[JBoss Nightly Builds](https://ci.jboss.org/jenkins/job/JBoss-AS-7.x-latest/) , just click on the link *Last Successful Artifact* there.